# How to submit form via Ajax in Django and reload only part of the page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to filter a simple database on companies without reloading the page, using Django/jQuery. On top of the page, there are a number of checkboxes, where the user can e.g. select countries. Below these checkboxes, there is a table containing the appropriate database entries. I'm trying to accomplish my goal using jQuery's load() function, but the entire page keeps reloading instead of just the div id that I need.

My template (main_view.html) looks something like this:

```
<form id="filters">
<input type="checkbox" id="USA" name="s" value="USA">USA
<input type="checkbox" id="UK" name="s" value="UK">UK
<button id="submitButtonId">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="companylist">
<tr>
  <td><b>Name</b></td>
  <td><b>Country</b></td>
</tr>
{% for company in companies %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ company.country }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>

<script>
$("#submitButtonId").click(function() {
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/",
  dataType: "html",
  data: $("#filters").serialize(),
  success: function(data)
  {
      $(#companylist).load('?' + data #companylist)
  }
  });
return false;
});
</script>
```

My views.py is structured like this:

```
def main_view(request):
  filter_countries = request.GET.getlist('c')
  if filter_query:
      companies = Company.objects.filter(country__in=filter_countries)
  else:
      companies = Company.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'database/main_view.html', {'companies': companies})
```

Comment: You are trying to update the DOM with Ajax and JQuery. Django, or whatever backend you're using doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt post main-view.html code. Make sure this html template is only the part you want to refresh. Not the entire page

Comment: This is main_view.html (except for the <head>).